# Pyspark -- Remove all-alphabets elements from array

Tags: pyspark

I have an array column like [abc, 123, ab12] in my df, would like to remove those elements which are pure alphabets in this array, so the output will be [123, ab12] for this example. Is there any built-ins to avoid using udf?

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

You can filter with an appropriate regex:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.withColumn('arr', F.expr("filter(arr, x -> x not rlike '^[a-z]*$')"))
```